# In Java, is it possible to use a method/constructor's parameter as a switch statement, case constant?

Tags: java, switch-statement

In a switch case, I've noticed that when I try to use a parameter as a case constant, I get a compilation error. But I can use fields/local vars.

Is it really impossible to use a parameter as a case constant? Or are there exceptions (if so, please provide an example)?

Example:

```
final int field = 0;
void method( final int parameter) {
    switch( 3) {
        case field: // ALLOWED
        case parameter; // NOT ALLOWED
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the parameter directly. I'm not interested in solutions that save the value of the parameter in a local var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much like C and C++, Java only allows *compile-time* constants as a value for `case`.

The value of *initialised* `final` class members can be determined at compile time and cannot change. `final` method parameters can have a different value at each method call.

To compare with method parameters, you probably have to fall back on good-old `if...else...`.

EDIT:

By the way, note the emphasis on *initialised* above. A `final` class member without an initialiser at the declaration cannot be used in as a `case` value either.

Answer (score 2):

java can use only constants in the `case` part